# Flutter: Delayed Animation with TweenAnimationBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello flutter developers,

I want to create a delayed animation with list of `Widgets` (each resulting in a singleListTile === customized ListTile) and `TweenAnimationBuilder`.

I'm using `Opacity` so each item will fade in after some time.
In my current solution the `duration` just streches, which is bad. My desired solution is a delay for each animation.

My goal is to have a very simple and efficient way to use a delay within TweenAnimationBuilder.

My guess is that a customized `function` or `curve` is necessary to simulate this kind of delay.

Please consider that i want to stay within or around `TweenAnimationBuilder`. I do not want to create `StaggeredAnimations` or other objects outside it.

Here is the current code:

```dart
Column buildContent(BuildContext context) => Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    for (var i = 0; i < itemList.length; i++)
      TweenAnimationBuilder(
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 560 + 140 * i),
          tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0),
          builder: (context, value, child) =>
              Opacity(opacity: value, child: child),
          child: singleListTile(itemList[i], context)),
  ],
);
```

In the image below you can see what happens in the code (left side) and what the desired solution (with delays) should look like.

I look forward to your creative responses.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use another TweenAnimationBuilder to do delay animation.

```
TweenAnimationBuilder<double>(
        tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1),
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100 * i),
        builder: (context, animatedValue, child) {
          if (animatedValue == 1) {
            return AnimatedChild;
          }
          return Container();
        },
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that might answer this. However, it's not very customizable and maybe requires more tweaks:

```dart
Column buildContent(BuildContext context) => Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    for (var i = 0; i < itemList.length; i++)
      TweenAnimationBuilder(
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 560 + 140 * i),
          curve: Curves.easeInCubic,
          tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0),
          builder: (context, value, child) => Opacity(
              opacity: delayedProgress(animationValue, i),
              child: child),
          child: singleListTile(itemList[i], context)),
  ],
);
```

The function

```
...

  double delayedProgress(double animationValue, int i) =>
      ((animationValue * completedExercises.length.toDouble()) -
              (i / completedExercises.length))
          .clamp(0, 1)
          .toDouble();
...
```

The function basically forces values only in the range of 0 and 1 with `clamp`, is multiplied by `animation.value` and the `itemList.length` and is finally removed by the current index divided by the maximum length (for smoothness).

Comment: This will not respect easeIn curve.

Answer (score 0):

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double delayRatio = delay.inMilliseconds == 0
        ? 0
        : delay.inMilliseconds.toDouble() /
            (delay.inMilliseconds.toDouble() +
                duration.inMilliseconds.toDouble());
    return TweenAnimationBuilder(
      tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0),
      duration: Duration(
          milliseconds: delay.inMilliseconds + duration.inMilliseconds),
      builder: (context, value, child) {
        if (value < delayRatio) {
          return Opacity(
            opacity: 0,
            child: this.child,
          );
        }
        value = (value - delayRatio) / (1 - delayRatio);
        return Transform.translate(
          offset: Offset(xOffset - xOffset * value, yOffset - yOffset * value),
          child: Opacity(
            opacity: value,
            child: this.child,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

this is my solution

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).